# how can chrome 32 and 64 bits coexist

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, 64-bit, 32-bit

My question is if there is a specific way to make coexist chrome 32 and 64 bits version. I have a windows 7 64 bits and I recently install chrome 64 bits to test some java applets, surprisingly the 64 bits version is installed in the 32 bits folder (`C:\Program Files (x86)`) overriding the 32 bit version. Actually the installer creates two `exe` files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application` `chrome.exe` and `old_chrome.exe`. First I suppose that `chrome.exe` opens the 64 bit version and `old_chrome.exe` opens the 32 bit. However both open 64 bits version.

I need the two versions installed to make test with both, I don't care about plugins (I know that there are some plugins that doesn't work, and for example flash hasn't a 64 bit version), the thing is that I want to have both versions installed correctly on the same machine. Is there a way or workaround to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable which is essentially a clever start-script pointing to the chrome-files in some local folder.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: DavidPostill: have you read my answer?

Comment: Yes. You could point out **why** it works, for example self-contained in a single directory with sub-directories and files within, doesn't leave entries in registry ... that would make it a better answer.

Comment: "which is essentially a clever start-script pointing to the chrome-files in some local folder." ... if this does not satisfy you: feel free to edit.

Comment: @akira, thanks `:)` a portable app it's a good option, I don't know how can't I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Like @akira answers a portable app could be a good option, another option is to install the `chorme canary` release: http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html

This chrome flavor it's for developers and due this it's probably not very stable, however IMO it's also a good choice because `chrome` 32 bits and `chrome canary` 64 bits can coexists and besides canary it's and official release from google.

Answer (score 1):

There a 4 different Channel versions of Chrome. See https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9027636 for ref. I would run a Channel in x64 and another Channel in x86 :

- Stable channel
- Beta channel
- Dev channel
- Canary build

As per Google, see https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel, they can be run side-by-side :

> All channels may be run in parallel -- they install into distinct directories and use dedicated User Data directories.

The Beta channel is pretty stable, much more so than the Dev and Canary and could pretty much fit the bill for your purpose.

Other advantages over the Portable Apps versions:

- it comes straight from the source (Google)
- standalone offline installers are available
- impervious to bugs that are sometimes associated with the Portable Apps versions of an application (not always the case, YMMV), like trouble updating, mixed up profiles and AppData
- Portable Apps sometimes lag behind in updates

Comment: This is a late answer but it's complete and well explained, thanks :). +1.